# Using switch button to set text visibility in another activity

Tags: java, android, onactivityresult

Am a beginner in android development and am desperately looking for a solution for a challenge i encountered while working on a quiz app.
I have a switch in my `SettingsActivity` which toggle set a particular text in another activity visible and invisible.
However i have been having problems finding the right logic to reference that text from my `SettingsActivity` in other to toggle its visibility.

**QuizActivity.java**

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 mExplanationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtExplanation); //this is the text with which i want the visibility to be controlled from SettingsActivity
}
}
```

**SettingsActivity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/explanationText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:fontFamily="cursive"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/settings_text"
            android:text="@string/explanation"/>
        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/explanationSwitch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
  private Switch mExplanationSwitch;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
  mExplanationSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.explanationSwitch);
  mExplanationSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
          // how do i toggle visibility of mExplanation text in my QuizActivity.java from here?
            }
        });
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
//This is where i start Quiz Activity
 private Button startQuiz;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 startQuiz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
   startQuiz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent startQuiz = new Intent(this, QuizActivity.class);
                startActivity(beginnerIntent);

        });

}
```

Comment: See How to manage startActivityForResult on Android?
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Comment: hello BennyKeys , use the code below in my answer it will work as your problem solution.

Comment: Use intent by passing the bundle information for toggle..and once the QuizActivity intent starts...check the bundle information using if(bundle<condition>){ set the mExplanationText visibility..}..Hopes this will help you..

Comment: thanks for the answer but can you please give me a code snippet or a link of an example where this was applied?

Comment: @Bennykeys where do you start quizactivity? Post the code

Comment: i have posted it. review my code

Comment: i have posted it. review my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Save Setting in Shared Preferences

```
mExplanationSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                                        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("SETTINGS", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                        Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                                        if(isChecked){
                                            editor.putBoolean("ntoificatoin",isChecked);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            editor.putBoolean("ntoificatoin",isChecked);

                                        }

                                        editor.apply();
                                        // how do i toggle visibility of mExplanation text in my QuizActivity.java from here?
                                    }
                                });
```

#### In Your QuizActivity

```
   public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

                                            @Override
                                            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                                                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                                                mExplanationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtExplanation); //this is the text with which i want the visibility to be controlled from SettingsActivity

                                                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("SETTINGS", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                                boolean b=preferences.getBoolean("ntoificatoin",false);//it returns stored boolean value else returns false


                                                if(b){

                                                    //return true from Settings 
                                                    //do what you want to
                                                    mExplanationText.setText("   "+b);
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    //return false from Settings 
                                                    //do what you want to
                                                    mExplanationText.setText("   "+b);

                                                }

                                            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you. you just saved my day. how could i ever repay you?

Comment: welcome bro . answer the questions if you know the answer in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for how to pass extra info to the QuizActivity here how to use the extra in the intent :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("stateOfTheSwitch","clicked");
startActivity(intent);
```

and in the QuizActivity you can retrieve the extra like this :

```
if(getIntent().getExtras.getString("stateOfTheSwitch").equals("clicked")
//do something
else
//do something else
```